# Sorting items alphabetically within a dynamic HTML select WITHOUT using JavaScript

Tags: html, jquery, model-view-controller, razor-pages

I was trying to sort items in the HTML Select element/drop-down list alphabetically. I was advised to "not do it in JavaScript", which is strange because every example I found was in JavaScript. There are no inline " elements within the HTML/View; most of it is done in JS and in SQL, and the form is empty in the view. Any tips on how I can accomplish this? The resulting drop-down is in the wrong order, but there are ID numbers when I use the Inspector tool within my browser.

When I create new options within the View based on the IDs in the Database, I get duplicates. I have also tried recreating the drop-down to display inline and hide the "empty" drop-down list.

Note: I was told to order it BEFORE it returns the data in JS.

**The View:**

```js
function getListTabName() {

listTabName = [];

$('#tabNameSelect').append(\<option value='' selected>Select an option</option>`);`

$.ajax({

type: "GET",

url: '/ClinicalManagement/TabName',

contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

dataType: 'json',

success: function (response) {

listTabName = response || [];

$.each(listTabName, function (idx, item) {

$('#tabNameSelect').append(\<option value='${item.TabId}'>${item.TabName}</option>`);`

});

},

error: function (xhr) {

}

});

}
```

```html
<div class="row form-group">

<div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">

<select id="tabNameSelect" class="form-control">

</select>

<label for="tabNameSelect"><span class="warningLabel" hidden> Cannot be Empty </span></label>

</div>

</div>
```

**JS File:**

```
function getListTabName() {

listTabName = [];

$('#tabNameSelect').append(\<option value='' selected>Select an option</option>`);`

$.ajax({

type: "GET",

url: '/ClinicalManagement/TabName',

contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

dataType: 'json',

success: function (response) {

listTabName = response || [];

$.each(listTabName, function (idx, item) {

$('#tabNameSelect').append(\<option value='${item.TabId}'>${item.TabName}</option>`);`

});

},

error: function (xhr) {

}

});

}
```

Comment: Your data comes from `/ClinicalManagement/TabName`. Presumably a server-side method that calls a database. You need to look at that area of the app, and understand how the data is retrieved and then do some research on the options available to you.